# Spring 2.5.4 return a integer on ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, prototypejs

I am working on a spring 2.5.4 project, where I need to get an ajax response that returns a integer value on ajax request. Is there is some way I can do it?

For now, I believe all ajax calls either returns a page or a part of page.

The sample code I am using for ajax request with prototype is as follows,

```
var ajaxSourceTable = new Ajax.Request(
    '../fetch/timeout.html?ajax=true',
    {   method:'post', 
        parameters:{}, 
        onSuccess:function(t){
            /*alert time out here*/
            alert(t.responseText); 
        }, 
        onFailure:function(t){
            alert("Request failed ! Please report the issue : "+t.responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `../fetch/timeout.html?ajax=true` has to return the single value. You should rather write a controller for that which return `text/plain` or `application/json` with the data in the response body.

Comment: Could you please provide some pointers to some sample or code snippet :( I could not figure it out myself..Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, make yourself acquiant with [1](http://perfectionlabstips.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/serving-json-data-with-spring-mvc-2/), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852448/spring-2-5-and-json).
Do not forget to set the response type to `application/json`. This will enable you to retrieve the object directly with Prototype `t.responseJson`.

In general, google for `spring 2.5 controller return json`.